# Content negotiation and extended media types

Tags: http, content-negotiation

Some media types are extensions of other media types.  Such media types often use + in their name to signal this.  For example, application/atom+xml extends generic xml and application/hal+json extends generic json.

My question is: what should be done if a client requests the generic media type and the server wants to respond with one of the extended media types?  For example, if a request has the header `Accept: application/json` and the server wants to respond with application/hal+json, should the server...

1. ...deliver a plain-jane JSON with `Content-type: application/json`, i.e. don't include `_links` or `_embedded`s?  That's what the client asked for and that's what it gets.  If you wants HAL, ask for it.
2. ...deliver the HAL representation with `Content-type: application/json`?  HAL, after all IS json and that's what the client asked for.  The client is happy and can ignore the bits it doesn't understand.
3. ...deliver the HAL representation with `Content-type: application/hal+json`?  Like 2., the client gets what it wants and can ignore the bits it doesn't understand.  But there's also a clue that the client can get more out of the representation.

My preference is 3.  But is there a spec, best practice, or commonly used approach that can provide guidance which is the best choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server may do any of the three, or it may respond with `406 Not Acceptable` if it is unwilling to respond with a default representation.

See: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.6

Comment: Thanks for the link to RFC 7231. I have been too long clinging to my well-thumbed printout of RFC 2616. I just tossed it and printed this and its companions.  Now if I can just stop clinging to paper :-)